# How to select child attribute in inline style html

Tags: html, css, inline, display

In css it's possible this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  section br {
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```

How to do that but in inline tag, for example:

```
<section style="section br { display:none;}  ">
         <br />
         <br />
         <br />
         <br />
</section>
```

My intention is not display tag 
 inside some specific section, but I can use just inline, not possible in this case with external css or tag inside

Cold someone help me, it would be amazing!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: *You can't do that.*

It is not possible to add inline styles that can also be applied to the child.  You can refer to [the style attribute spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/) (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/) which succinctly, albeit somewhat cryptically, explains it.

> The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents
> of a CSS declaration block (excluding the delimiting braces)...
>
> ***The declarations in a style attribute apply to the element to which the***
> ***attribute belongs***. In the cascade, these declarations are considered
> to have author origin and a specificity higher than any selector.
> CSS2.1 defines how style sheets and style attributes are cascaded
> together. [CSS21] Relative URLs in the style data must be resolved
> relative to the style attribute's element (or to the document if
> per-element resolution is not defined) when the attribute's value is
> parsed.
>
> Aside from the differences in cascading, the declarations in a style
> attribute must be interpreted exactly as if they were given in a CSS
> style rule that applies to the element.