# How to add first-child selector in style attribute

Tags: html, css

Example: `<div class="col-12" style=":first-child { display: none; }">`

I don't have access to styles, so I need to fix that in the html file, can I add first-child selector right in the style attribute? The example doesn't work.

Comment: can you add a `<style>` tag? otherwise it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646683/how-to-add-nth-child-style-in-inline-styling)

Comment: No, thanks for the reply anyway

Comment: It's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646683/how-to-add-nth-child-style-in-inline-styling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344453/how-to-select-child-attribute-in-inline-style-html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833075/can-inline-css-apply-to-child-elements-nested-in-the-styled-element